# What is a good Hash Function for limit range output

Tags: c#, hash

I need a hash function to map 1000 number to a 50*50 matrix.my numbers is 8 digits hex.i use:

```
static int[,] matrix = new int[50, 50];
int m=hex[0 to 3]%50;
int n=hex[4 to 7]%50;
matrix[m,n]++;
```

but it very bad function and have very Collision.in fact i will count number of of source IP in a network packet window.
please help me!

Comment: You can't map 4 billions (*0xFFFFFFFF*) potential numbers to 2500 numbers without collisions with a generic hash

Comment: just 1000 number hashed and find Abundance of any number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class guarantess that there are no collisions :-) Note that the returned hashes are sequential. The hash of the first distinct number given will be 0, the hash of the second distinct number given will be 1 and so on.

```
public class Hasher
{
    private readonly Dictionary<int, int> Hashes = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    public int Hash(int value)
    {
        int hash;

        if (!Hashes.TryGetValue(value, out hash))
        {
            hash = Hashes.Count;
            Hashes[value] = Hashes.Count;
        }

        return hash;
    }
}
```

Use like this:

```
var hasher = new Hasher();
int hash1 = hasher.Hash(11); // 0
int hash2 = hasher.Hash(27); // 1
int hash3 = hasher.Hash(11); // 0
int hash4 = hasher.Hash(47); // 2
int hash5 = hasher.Hash(47); // 2
```

Comment: @user1125774 You can't have an handwriting algorithm. You can't select 2500 hashes for the 1000 values you'll have because you can't know which values they'll be.

Comment: I am a student doing a class project

Comment: Quite true, but I need to have an appropriate level Not entirely without fault

Comment: @user1125774 Then simply dividing the full space as you are doing (with % 50) is the best way.

Comment: @user1125774 UNLESS you have some statistics that tell you that the distribution of the numbers isn't homogeneous, and that perhaps there are more numbers < 1000000 than there are numbers > 1000000. Then you can optimize the algorithm